# show collapse panel and edit other panel class

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show collapse panel with a button then edit other panel's class so it could fit on page width. here is my code

button

```js
// first try
$('#signup').on('click', function() {
  $('#table').removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-8');
});
// second try
$('#signup').on('click', function() {
  $('#table').toggleClass('col-md-12 col-md-8');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel" id="signup">Signup</button>

<div class="form-row">
  <!-- panel 1 -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 collapse" id="panel">
    // stuff here
  </div>

  <!-- panel 2 -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 ml-auto" id="table">
    // stuff here
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, I want panel 1 show up, and then panel 2 class col-md-12 change to col-md-8, so it can fit bootstrap grid system. I try onclick trigger but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the onClick code you tried?

Comment: is `tabel` typo just here or in code too?

Comment: typo here, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to combine the method and finally it works.

```js
$('#panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $('#table').removeClass('col-md-8').addClass('col-md-12');
});
$('#signup').on('click', function(){
    $('#table').removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-8');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $('#table').toggleClass('col-xs-12').toggleClass('col-xs-8');
}).on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $('#table').toggleClass('col-xs-8').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
})
```

```css
.form-row.row {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel" id="signup">Signup</button>

<div class="form-row row">
  <!-- panel 1 -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-4 collapse" id="panel">
    // stuff here  Panel 1
  </div>

  <!-- panel 2 -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ml-auto" id="table">
    // stuff here  Panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

An updated snippet that does not use the Bootstrap grid system.

```js
$('#panel').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $('#table').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
}).on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  $('#table').toggleClass('col-xs-12');
})
```

```css
.some-sontainer {
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.some-sontainer .col1{
  width: 200px;
}

.some-sontainer .col2{
  width: 100%;
}

#table{
  background-color: red;
}

#panel{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel" id="signup">Signup</button>

<div class="form-row some-sontainer">
  <!-- panel 1 -->
  <div class="form-group col1 collapse" id="panel">
    // stuff here  Panel 1
  </div>

  <!-- panel 2 -->
  <div class="form-group col2 col-xs-12 ml-auto" id="table">
    // stuff here  Panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its not like that, i want panel 1 and panel 2 in one row and panel two shrink to the right with class col-md-8 when panel 1 show up

Comment: This was your css selection. I made the changes to make divs in a row.

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work, it just shrink panel 2 to the right even without panel 1 show up.

Comment: How? When I run the snippet, and click the button, panel 1 collapses and expands accordingly. I changed the content, so you can see that it does show and hide.

Comment: I don't know how but I've copy your css and modified form class but panel 2 shrink to the right which is like adding table-responsice to the class. Your snippet works perfectly but I don't get it why it doesn't work on my page

Comment: Some screenshots will be helpful. One for what you have, and another one for what you want. When I run the snippet here, it looks fine.

Comment: Before panel 1 show up https://ibb.co/fJF1gb. After panel 1 show up https://ibb.co/eVQdSG. I want it like this https://ibb.co/itLZ1b

Comment: We are talking about a complete different issue than the original question. You selected the Bootstrap grid system to arrange your div. It is known to enforce width in percentage. This is why you are having this additional spacing between your columns. What Bootstrap version are you using? I added a snippet that assumes Bootstrap 3.X for your UI. There are many ways to handle what you are looking for. I only used one of them. You will need to test and select what is better for your website.

Comment: I use bootstrap 4 as I include in tags. Meanwhile, I'll try with a different method. Thanks anyway

Comment: OK. I updated the second snippet to have a behavior similar to your screenshot.